# Is some last digit more frequent in primes than some or all the other?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let us denote by $E_1(1,10,n)$ the number of primes in an interval $[1,10^n]$ that end in digit $1$. Define in the same way $E_3(1,10,n)$ and $E_7(1,10,n)$ and $E_9(1,10,n)$.

> What are the values of the limits $$L_{g,h}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {E_g(1,10,n)}{E_h(1,10,n)}$$, where $g,h \in \{1,3,7,9\}$?

Comment: Although this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720 concerns itself with the least significant digits of consecutive primes, it is still of some relevance to your question.

Comment: look at primes in arithmetic progressions that may help. as that's what 10n+y digit y is.

Answer (score 1):

Look up prime races. It depends on whether the last digit is a quadratic residue mod 10.

Comment: there's a lot it can relate to sadly.